# Azure Pipeline - exe install hanging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, exe

Having an unusual issue where as part of a step in my Azure Pipeline, i am installing an application (.exe) via cmd/script.

The self hosted agent is running on my PC. When the pipeline triggers the exe install step (quite/headless mode) , the installer hangs.
If I run the same command from my command prompt, it installs fine.

Tested with notepad++ to see if it was an issue with my own application and same probelem exists.

Do i need to specify any additional privileges when installing an exe from Azure pipeline